# bind value global variable to object with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object which is declared as following (it has as value a global variable):

```
var example = {
    "foo": window.bar
}
```

Steps after other method is executed and this value change, but if I want to use the value in the object, this is `undefined`.

The listeners seem to be exclusively to DOM elements but not to values, There is a way to bind the value at the object to a variable or something that update the value in the object?

here a example what I want to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/ptbqqk6o/2

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is not a JSON object. Please read the `json` tag description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`example.foo` is undefined as soon as you execute the assignment to `example`: the value of `window.bar` is resolved at that very moment, which does not yet exist in your case, ... so `undefined`.

If you want to maintain a reference to an object that can *mutate* in the future, then define `window.bar` first, before the assignment to `example`, and define it as an object. Then, never reassign a value to `window.bar`, but only *mutate* it: that way the reference will remain shared:

```js
window.bar = {}; // An object, for later mutation.

var obj = {
    foo: window.bar // a reference to the above object
}

window.bar.message = "this works!";

console.log(obj.foo);
```

Comment: Thank you, I just edited my question with your suggestion. Where can I find further information about mutator and how this works?

Comment: I would advise to read about JavaScript's way of passing arguments: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language). It is not exactly the same subject, but I think if you understand that, you'll see the light on what happens when you assign a new value to a variable as opposed to what happens if you *mutate* it, i.e. you change a property value of the variable's (object) value, but don't change the variable via direct assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In the code in your fiddle:

```
var json = {
    foo : window.bar
}

window.some = 'bar';

alert(json.foo);
```

When you construct the jsonExample object, the value of window.bar has not yet been set.  Thus jsonExample.foo is set to undefined.  Try this:

```
window.bar = 'bar';

var json = {
    foo : window.bar
}

alert(json.foo);
```